# Using ufw to block established telnet connection

Tags: firewall, telnet, ufw

I'm trying to learn ufw and I'm wondering if I can block established connections with it.

I've made connection between my 2 computers using telnet and I'm trying to use ufw to block it.

Tried many rules, but with no effect:

```
ufw deny in from IP to any
ufw deny out from IP to any
ufw deny in from any to IP
ufw deny out from any to IP
ufw deny port 23
```

Telnet connection is still functioning. If I close connection and then I'm trying to connect again, ufw is blocking telnet correctly, but I want to know why I can't block already established connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ufw implements a *stateful* firewall, where only the "opening" packet is checked against the port-based rules, but the rest of the connection is immediately accepted by a hidden "allow packets known by conntrack" rule and doesn't need to go through the rest of your ruleset.

*(In iptables, this would be the `-m state --state ESTABLISHED` rule.)*

You can use the `conntrack` command to delete state entries for existing connections:

```
conntrack -D -s <bad_ip>

conntrack -D -p tcp --dport 23
```

(In theory, 'ufw deny' *could* remove conntrack states automatically. But perhaps it deliberately doesn't, so that people wouldn't lock themselves out of remote servers if they accidentally block the SSH port.)